# Use multipe emacs modes in one file

Tags: emacs

I have a question about using the emacs modes within a shell script. It's often so, that I wrote just some pieces of code in PHP for example like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

export FILENAME=$1

php -r '

  $xml = new SimpleXmlIterator(getenv("FILENAME"), null, true);

  echo "//" . $xml->attributes()["name"] . "\n";
  echo "struct " . $sxi->attributes()["type"] . " {\n";

  php blabla
'

cat FILENAME | while read x
do
.... shell blabla
```

Because of the shebang the emacs mode is forced to shell mode, which is correct.

But is there a trick to use the php mode "within" the part where php code is written?
(without to kick out the php in its own script)

Comment: maybe something like https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode ? (I personally haven't used it for a long time)

Comment: Sounds interesting. BTW: This repo has the oldest commits I've never been seen.

Comment: it was only 21 years ago...

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes